# Bridge interface - add default route

Tags: networking, routing, bridge

I used to connect my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop on office network via `eth0` and the route table gets updated with the office network gateway IP in `auto` mode.

Now, I changed my `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration to add a bridge interface, `br0`, and made `eth0` as a dumb port inside `br0`. 
My `/etc/network/interfaces` has:

```
iface br0 inet static
   address X.X.X.X
   netmask 255.255.0.0
   bridge_ports eth0
   bridge_stp on
   bridge_fd 0
   gateway X.X.X.X
```

My route table is no longer getting updated. Every time I plug in my ethernet cable, I need to do:

`route add default gw X.X.X.X br0`

How to configure the default gateway for a bridge?

Comment: I have the same problem on a machine with Ubuntu 16.04. In fact, the default gateway is created, but it uses the eth0 device underlying the bridge and this interface is marked as down. Manually setting the default gateway as mentioned in the question works.

Answer (score 2):

The default gateway normally gets updated by dhcp.

However, in your `/etc/network/interfaces`, you state that, for `br0` the inet is static. You specify explicitly the IP address, netmask and gateway. So, no dhcp request is done for this interface.

If you want the default gateway updated, specify as:

```
auto br0
    iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
```